# Resize tableview frame to fit dynamic contents using cell size autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, ios9

When I resize my `tableView`, content is cut off because `contentSize` seems to be determined by `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 18`.

The actual `contentSize` of the `tableView` (adjusted for autolayout) is larger than `sizeToFit()` thinks it is.

How do I tell `sizeToFit()` the correct size of my `tableView` contents?

```
 tableView.frame = CGRectMake( 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.height + 18, self.view.frame.size.width, 350 )
 tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 18
 tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

 self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
 tableView.sizeToFit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I tell sizeToFit() the correct size of my tableView contents

You don't. The table view, as a view, knows nothing of how many rows it has or even that you think it should be the height of its rows. (It can't read your mind.) You must calculate its height *yourself* based on the the number of rows and their heights.

Comment: how do I get the size of the cells after autolayout adjusts them?

Comment: A cell is a view. Just look at its height.

Comment: correct answer was to get each cell height in viewDidAppear.  which will account for autolayout height adjustments.                                                for cell in self.tableView.visibleCells {
                 newTableHeight = newTableHeight + cell.frame.height
            }